# How to access global stackexchange user favourites in a feed?

Tags: support, api, rss

I was looking for a way to IFTTT my questions, and found [this recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/62544), that automaqically saves your favourited questions to Evernote. Nice. It uses stack2rss (thus the SE API) to provide a feed with this URL `http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/ID/favorites?body=true`

Now I want to do the same for the [all the favourites](http://stackexchange.com/users/6683/charlesb?tab=favorites) I have on SE sites, but can't find how to do it in API. I tried to replace `stackoverflow` by `stackexchange` or `stackexchange.com`, but it returns an error.

Is it possible?

Comment: https://ifttt.com/recipes/62544 can't view

Comment: http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/ID/favorites?body=true   site not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use the Stack Exchange user ID: http://stackexchange.com/users/login.
This is the `account_id`, to be more precise.

With that, run the [User's associated accounts](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users) method.

Iterate through the results [running another query](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/favorites-on-users) (with your `user_id` in each site) to build the favorites:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "site_name": "Stack Overflow",
      "site_url": "http://stackoverflow.com",
      "user_id": 1287812,
      "reputation": 4841,
      "account_id": 1211516,
      "creation_date": 1332491688,
      "badge_counts": {
        "gold": 6,
        "silver": 12,
        "bronze": 35
      },
      "last_access_date": 1377657230,
      "answer_count": 288,
      "question_count": 9
    },
    // ET CETERA
```